# DataGridView.rows.Cells.Style.BackColor doesn't work with MdiParent in form load event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

It really drives me crazy, I have a form, I am calling a public sub called "timerss" in the form load event, when i run my form the sub "timerss" works perfectly, but when i add "**Me.MdiParent = MDIParent1**" in load event the sub "timerss" doesn't work!! i am really confused here!! any idea please.

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.MdiParent = MDIParent1
    timerss()
End Sub
```

update1:\ check the print screen of the result when running my form with and without setting MdiParent!
[image]

**update2**: I managed to fix part of the problem which is i got the data but what i want now is to set the color of the time cells with red, as i said the sub don't want to work, the timerss sub is:

```
For m As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(4).Value > DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(9).Value Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                MsgBox("red")
            End If
        Next
```

as u c in the above code i put a msgbox just to make sure that the code is working, so when i run my form the msgbox appears, but the backcolor function doesn't work when i set the MdiParent.

Comment: unfortunately nobody here is telepathic.  "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything at all.

Comment: put a breakPoint in Me.MdiParent an see if is Nothing or Null ..

Comment: @Dan-o : I don't know how to explain it more than what i said, the sub as i said doesn't work when i set the MdiParent, and it works without MdiParent! what u want more!?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the behavior is different without MDIParent, but you could try calling the sub from the DataBindingComplete event.
I had a similar problem and solved it using the event.